# Alerts for A View not working as expected

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, sharepoint-server

We have a library that includes a column with 3 choices.  We have made a view that display all items where choice = Option2.  We subsequently set alerts on new items added to that view and for testing alerts for the base library.  Users will receive alerts set for all new docs and will not receive alerts for docs that fit a view.

I have verified that all web servers and app servers can send email.  I checked logs and have verified that immediate alerts jobs run and are sent and received, just not for the alerts based on a view.

What else can I check?  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

You can only setup alerts on a View if the View is filtered by a Choice column.  Is your view filtered by a choice column?  Also alerts will not work for the views if there is a filter based on a System Generated or Calculated column.

Comment: It is set up on a required choice column.  The disconnect seems to be that the file upload is a two step process.  Upload creates file.  Metadata modifies entry.  Therfore the trigger "on new item" doesn't coincide with "has choice value".