# Can I alert on new items in a specific view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

Continuation of question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264500/alerts-for-a-view-not-working-as-expected)
I've created a filtered view based on a choice column.  How can I make an alert that will only trigger the first time a document is uploaded that meets the choice view criteria? I don't want alerts for changes after the upload.

My testing indicates that this is impossible as item creation happens on upload, but the dialog box where the choice is made triggers a modification and is not part of the item creation.  I also attempted to use a default choice tied to a folder and then upload directly to the folder to see if the change would happen fast enough.  It still didn't work.  So I exposed the Version column in the view.  All items were showing 1.0 and not 2.0 as I expected.  I don't know what is going on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continued testing despite results.  Here was our solution that worked.  The alert does not respect, in conjunction, the settings "only new things" and "only in a certain view".

So we made a view with a filter on the choice column AND a filter for Version = 1.0.  Then we created an alert on ALL changes, but it only triggered the first time (creation) because the view had the version filter.

The only drawback to this solution was that we have extra views that no one wants to see just for the alert.  We have to name them such that it is evident what to select for future alerts.  They have to be named such that they are at the lowest alphabetical index.  And the link to the view in the email is relatively useless.

The other answers here are good choices for anyone who wants to use them.  They work.  But as this was our final solution, I'm going to mark it as the answer and give +1 to the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

A completly different approach could be to set up a search query in a search center and request a notification once the search result changes?

Comment: This is a good suggestion. I've never set one up. +1

Answer (score 1):

Create a workflow to send an email in place of the alert.

Basic setup:
In your list/library create a new column titled WFRan (default value is No).

In the workflow use the same criteria you setup in your View.
If fieldA = B and WFRan = No
send email
set WFRan = Yes

Comment: Thanks.  This is my fall back option.  I just want to verify that alerts can't do what it looks like they should be able to do.

Comment: @Jammin4CO if you go this route, do not rely on the workflow column that is added to the list.  the data in that field might be deleted after X number of days as part of the workflow cleanup timer job, hence my suggestion to create a new field.

Answer (score 1):

Just as taco said, create a workflow attached to your library. Trigger the workflow when the there are file is created. Use an if condition to only send email when the option is 2.

[image]

Comment: I know I could build a workflow in SPD.  And I will if we can't figure out how to set up alerts to get the desired results.